# The Designer throws NullReference Exception

Tags: xaml, pivot, windows-phone-8, itemtemplate

What I need is to set the item frame margin to 10.

The Designer View keep throwing the Exception so I cant proceed.

```
<phone:Pivot.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <phone:PivotItem Margin="10"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</phone:Pivot.ItemTemplate>
```

What's wrong with this code?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I didn't realise this was WP8. On WP8, phone *is* the default namespace for Pivots. That's pretty arbitrary though. Are you sure that the problem isn't elsewhere? It would still be helpful for you to share your XAML, but here is some that works for me:

```
<phone:Pivot>
    <phone:Pivot.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <phone:PivotItem Margin="10">
                <Grid>
                    <!--Contents of template-->
                </Grid>
            </phone:PivotItem>
        </DataTemplate>
    </phone:Pivot.ItemTemplate>
    <phone:PivotItem Header="Hello">
        <Grid>
            <!--Contents of "Hello" item-->
        </Grid>
    </phone:PivotItem>
    <phone:PivotItem Header="World">
        <Grid>
            <!--Contents of "World" item-->
        </Grid>
    </phone:PivotItem>
</phone:Pivot>
```

Comment: Yes, the namespace seems to be phone for me. But I'd really want a template cause I need to add them dynamically in script. However your script (the 2nd one) didn't work for me cause it still gives a null exception

Comment: That's very peculiar... It worked fine for me in a completely blank project.

Comment: Are you writing all your xaml manually, or did you place a Pivot on the page and then edit it in xaml? Also, what version of Windows Phone are you targetting? 7.0/7.1/8.0?

Comment: Would it be possible for you to put your entire xaml file on pastebin or something so I can look at all of it?

Comment: It is 8.0 and the xaml is generated. How do I pastebin?

Comment: It's just a simple text sharing service. You can copy and paste your stuff there and then share the generated link here. Don't use it if your code is supersecret, as it will be publicly visible.

Comment: I tried out your code and saw no exceptions, but got a XAML Error that only went away when I removed the "toolkit" namespace and deleted all the animations.

After I did that, it worked fine for me.

Comment: Ok, I tried to delete all the tookit and its relative namespace. But I still get the NullReferenceError.